# Скопировать БД на другой сервер

Tags: sql-server

У меня есть БД. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно скопировать БД MSSQL на другой сервер?

Comment: Можно ли с мастером импорта/экспорта?

Comment: Backup, потом restore.

Answer (score 1):

Можно переместить файлы .mdf и.ldf и сделать attach